# NSIS Downloading timeout

Tags: java, nsis

I have build a NSIS and it have been working ok for few months, 
suddenly it got a problem for downloading fail for the JRE , i have tested the download link is ok plesase suggest the possible solution if someone can help part of the code was listed as following:

```
!define JRE_URL "javadl.sun.com/webapps/download/AutoDL?BundleId=69476"
Function GetJRE
    MessageBox MB_OK "${PRODUCT_NAME} uses Java ${JRE_VERSION}, it will now \
                     be downloaded and installed"
```

[image]

```
    StrCpy $2 "$TEMP\Java Runtime Environment.exe"
    nsisdl::download /TIMEOUT=30000 ${JRE_URL} $2
    Pop $R0 ;Get the return value
            StrCmp $R0 "success" +3
            MessageBox MB_OK "Download failed: $R0"
            Quit
    ExecWait $2
    Delete $2
FunctionEnd


Function DetectJRE

Push $0
Push $1

; for 64-bit registry
SetRegView 64
ReadRegStr $3 HKLM "SOFTWARE\JavaSoft\Java Runtime Environment" "CurrentVersion"
;MessageBox MB_OK "JRE CurrentVersion $3"
;StrCmp $3 ${JRE_VERSION} Done

StrCpy $0 $3 1 0
StrCpy $1 $3 1 2
StrCpy $4 "$0$1"
;MessageBox MB_OK "JR CurrentVersion $JR_VERSION"
;MessageBox MB_OK "JR CurrentVersion $4"
IntCmp 16 $4 Done JavaVerNotCorrect JavaVerNotCorrect # if not JRE 1.6,download from the web


JavaVerNotCorrect:
Call GetJRE

Done:
      Pop $1
      Pop $0
FunctionEnd
```

Comment: `JRE_URL` lacks the protocol, hence is not a valid URL

Comment: @idleberg, hi i also try http://javadl.sun.com/webapps/download/AutoDL?BundleId=52252 but without success

Comment: Try a valid URL prefixed with a protocol (e.g. `http://`)

Comment: @idleberg tried 
https:+//javadl.oracle.com/webapps/download/AutoDL?BundleId=69476
http:+//javadl.sun.com/webapps/download/AutoDL?BundleId=58134
both without success , but the URL is working out of the NSIS ~
the https was deleted in here only i dont know why

Answer (score 0, accepted):

nsisDl uses a custom HTTP library. Use [INetC](https://nsis.sourceforge.io/Inetc_plug-in) instead, it uses the same HTTP library as Internet Explorer.